# Invariant notion of pseudovector, again

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, definition

I know there is a lot of topics about pseudovectors (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117139/what-exactly-are-pseudovectors-and-pseudoscalars-and-where-could-i-read-about-t), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264771/cross-product-and-pseudovector-confusion/265524#265524), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247916/pseudovectors-in-geometry)), but I am not really satisfied with the answers in this topics, let me explain why.

Let $V$ is some vector space such that $\dim V = 3$, then in all topics above offer think about pseudovectors as about elements of $\wedge^2 V$, but for me pseudovector is element of $\star(\wedge^2 V)$ where $\star$ is Hodge star operator. So for me $a \wedge b$ is $2$-vector and $\star(a \wedge b)$ is pseudovector. The problem is after using hodge star on $2$-vector we can't remember that this is actually pseudovector.

So, i am interesting about next notion of pseudovector. Let $(V, \mathcal{O})$ is some vector space with fixed orientation and $\operatorname{inv} : (V, \mathcal{O}) \to (V, -\mathcal{O})$ is natural operator which reverse orientation, then pseudovector $p$ is such object that

1. Can be naturally constructed from vector $v \in (V,\mathcal{O})$, $p = p(v)$
2. Satisfied to identity $\operatorname{inv}(p(v)) = -p(\operatorname{inv}(v))$
3. Codomen of Hodge star restricted on $(\wedge^2 V, \wedge^2 \mathcal{O})$, is actually pseudovectors of $(V, \mathcal{O})$ not vectors.

Does such notion exists? Thank you.