# Understanding pseudovectors and pseudoscalars

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

In doing an exercise about pseudovectors

> How do the components of a cross product transform under inversion?

I got stuck. I didn't know how to compute the inversion of a cross product.

My naive approach was as follows. Say we we invert the cross product $\mathbf a = \mathbf b \times \mathbf c$ about the origin. We then have $\mathrm{inv} (\mathbf a) = \mathrm{inv} (a_x,a_y,a_z)=(-a_x,-a_y,-a_z)$, and we're done.

This means $\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf a) = (-)\mathbf a = - \mathbf b \times \mathbf c$.

At this point I have no means of checking whether this is correct or not.

Hence, I now choose $\mathbf b = \hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\mathbf c =\hat{\mathbf{y}}$, so that $\mathbf a = \hat{\mathbf z}$.

Now, $\mathrm{inv}(\hat{\mathbf z}) = -\hat{\mathbf z} = - \hat{\mathbf x} \times \hat{\mathbf y} $.

This I can check, using the right-hand rule.

$ - \hat{\mathbf x} \times \hat{\mathbf y}  = \hat{\mathbf y} \times \hat{\mathbf x} = - \hat{\mathbf z} .$

Hence, this seems to check out, in keeping with my naive calculations. **Why is this wrong?**

Reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264771/92180) and it's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264798/92180), I seem to have to calculate the inversion of $\mathbf a$ about the origin by inverting its components seperately: $\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf a) = \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf b) \times \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf c)$. **How could I have derived that you should invert the components $\mathbf b, \mathbf c$ seperately?**

In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264798/92180), the argument goes that we simply *define* the action of the linear operator $\mathrm{inv}$ on a bivector (?) that way. But how does this --- $\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf a) = \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf b) \times \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf c)$--- follow naturally?

Also, *bivectors* are associative. But cross products aren't. How is this relevant to the discussion?

If I would accept this *rule*, then my answer to my question is readily given: we simply have $$\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf b) \times \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf c) = (-\mathbf b) \times (-\mathbf c) = \mathbf a$$ hence the cross product is invariant under inversions.

My post relates directly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1117139/92180).

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117184/92180), to that question question attempts to answer my question by saying *the laws of physics are converved under coordinate inversion*, which I find unalluminating. I read this same sentence

> *One of the most powerful ideas in physics is that physical laws do not change when one changes the coordinate system used to describe
> these laws.*

in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) on pseudoscalars.

By using the same *rule* --- inverting the components seperately --- on the scalar triple product, the answer follows readily: $$\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf d \cdot \mathbf e \times \mathbf f) = \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf d) \cdot \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf e) \times \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf f)  = - \mathbf d \cdot \mathbf e \times \mathbf f \ .$$

My same question in this case: **how does this rule of inverting the seperate components follow naturally**?

**I want to deeply understand what relates pseudovectors and pseudoscalars to bivectors and trivectors respectively, in a clear way.** This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117361/92180), atttempts to relate them to the exterior and Clifford algebra, which I don't follow. It says that inversion changes the handedness of a trivector:

> Trivectors, too, are different from ordinary scalars.  All trivectors can be written as a scalar multiple of $\epsilon \equiv \hat x \wedge \hat y \wedge \hat z$, and we can interpret this as an **oriented volume**.  If some trivector $\tau = \alpha \epsilon$ for some positive $\alpha$, then $\tau$ is right-handed.  If $\alpha < 0$, then $\tau$ is left-handed.

What do we mean by changing the handedness?

I decided to ask this question on math.stackexchange instead of physics.stackexchange because the question relates to exterior- and Clifford algebra. I also haven't used any applications in physics in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You should imagine that when you take $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb R^3$ and compute $\mathbf x \times \mathbf y$, the result lives in a "different $\mathbb R^3$". We call elements of the first $\mathbb R^3$ "vectors", and elements of the second $\mathbb R^3$ "pseudovectors". It is legal to add two vectors together; it is legal to add two pseudovectors together; it is illegal to add a vector and a pseudovector.

So the question is:

> If we reflect the first $\mathbb R^3$ through the origin, what happens to the second $\mathbb R^3$?"

We have a transformation $\text{inv}$ that takes a vector $(x,y,z)$ to a vector $\text{inv}(x,y,z) = (-x,-y,-z)$. We also have a corresponding transformation, which you're also calling $\text{inv}$, but which I'll call for clarity $\text{inv}^{\times}$. It operates on the second $\mathbb R^3$, where pseudovectors live. We don't know what it does yet, but we'd like it to do something that plays nicely with cross product: we'd like to have
$$
    \text{inv}^\times(\mathbf x \times \mathbf y) = \text{inv}(\mathbf x) \times \text{inv}(\mathbf y).
$$
Now, if we apply the definition of cross product, we get that
$$
    \text{inv}(\mathbf x) \times \text{inv}(\mathbf y) = \det\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j & \mathbf k \\ -x_1 & -x_2 & -x_3 \\ -y_1 & -y_2 & -y_3\end{bmatrix} = (-1) \det\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j & \mathbf k \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ -y_1 & -y_2 & -y_3\end{bmatrix} = \\ = (-1)^2 \det\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf i & \mathbf j & \mathbf k \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ y_1 & y_2 & y_3\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf x \times \mathbf y.
$$
We conclude that $\text{inv}^\times$ must be the identity: $\text{inv}^\times(\mathbf z) = \mathbf z$ for all $\mathbf z$ in the "second $\mathbb R^3$".

Comment: Now, I'm interested in the *doing some algebra* part of your answer. How do arrive at that *beautiful* equality $$
    \text{inv}^\times(\mathbf x \times \mathbf y) = \text{inv}(\mathbf x) \times \text{inv}(\mathbf y)\ .
$$

Comment: I've edited my answer for the algebra. But if you're asking "how do we arrive at that equality", the answer is "we don't know what $\text{inv}^\times$ is yet, so we figure out what it must be in order to have that property."

Comment: I'm not following *we figure out what it must be in order to have that property*. Are you saying that we *want* $\mathrm{inv}^\times$ to have the identity property? Because in the post, you're assuming the identity from the start.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on what we mean by the handedness of the *trivector*?

Comment: Why do we want $\mathrm{inv}^\times$ to have the identity property? And once we know we want this property, how do we make the leap to operate $\mathrm{inv}^\times$ seperately on both vectors?

Comment: Sorry, we **want** $\text{inv}^\times(\mathbf x \times \mathbf y) = \text{inv}(\mathbf x) \times \text{inv}(\mathbf y).$. We deduce from this that  $\text{inv}^\times(\mathbf z) = \mathbf z$. I wasn't clear which identity you meant.

Comment: *Why* do we want $\mathrm{inv}(\mathbf x \times \mathbf y) = \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf y) \times \mathrm{inv}(\mathbf z)$? This is what my question revolves around. I don't know where this property comes from.